# unload dll's in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dll

Is there a tool in windows 7 that allows you to find and unload dll's? Without restarting the system. I am not looking to unload/upgrade/regsrv32.. Just looking to wipe out a couple dll's but they're loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are applications such as [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) or [UnlockIT](http://emcosoftware.com/unlock-it)  that claim to do this.

WARNING: Doing this could affect stability of your system and the integrity of your data.  I haven't used either of these applications, nor would I (unless it was an emergency).

Answer (score 0):

The fix is the same as for XP, under regedit, go to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer, add DWORD "AlwaysUnloadDLL" and give it a value of 1.

Reboot your machine, run some programs, then look at your taskmgr, you should see it free of DLL's

Comment: The OP clearly stated "Without restarting the system." Your answer requires rebooting.